# iOS: Is secure enclave shared between app extensions?

Tags: ios

I am working on a app where a encryption key is saved into the secure enclave. So my question is if this data is also shared with the app extensions, i.e. Siri / Notification Center widget / Watch App?

Answer (score -1):

`App Group` keychain items can be shared between the app and the app extension. See the instructions in [Sharing Access to Keychain Items Among a Collection of Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps)

`SecItemCopyMatching` will return an item saved by the app and queried for within the extension.

I use this approach in my app.

Note you do not have direct access to the secure enclave. This is where the private key is saved. You do however have access to the Keychain items (encrypted by the secure enclave private key).